# What is the syntax problem here using this subquery inside where clause

Tags: sql, db2

```
SELECT p.pnum, p.pname
FROM professor p, class c
WHERE p.pnum = c.pnum AND c.cnum = CS245 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT MAX(m.grade), MAX(m.grade) - MIN(m.grade) AS diff 
FROM mark m WHERE m.cnum = c.cnum AND m.term = c.term AND m.section = c.section AND diff <= 20)) = 3
```

Incorrect syntax near ')'.  Expecting AS, FOR_PATH, ID, or QUOTED_ID.

Comment: `c.cnum = CS245` should be `c.cnum = 'CS245'`

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please add the relevant tag to your question: mysql, oracle, sql-server...

Comment: What could you possibly intend this query to do?

Comment: @GMB thanks for that part, have updated tags

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not sure about my grammer, new to sql, it gives me error like said in the question, the error is at ')' before =3

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES T
WHERE 
(
--  SELECT COUNT(1) 
--  FROM
--  (
  SELECT COUNT(1) 
  FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS C 
  WHERE C.TABSCHEMA=T.TABSCHEMA AND C.TABNAME=T.TABNAME
--  )
) > 50;
```

The query above works as is. But the problem is, that if you uncomment the commented out lines, you get the following error message: `"T.TABNAME" is an undefined name.` and least in `Db2 for Linux, Unix and Windows`. 
You can't push external to the sub-select column references too deeply.

So, your query is incorrect.
It's hard to correct it, until you provide the task description with data sample and the result expected.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a potential syntax errors: It seems that CS245 refers to a value c.cnum may take and not a column name.  If that is the case, it should be enclosed in single quotes.